# Facebook Feed Dialog Javascript. Description property is deprecated. Replacement?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So i'm trying to implement a feature where the user can post his or her highscore of my game on Facebook with the help of Facebooks own feed dialog. But recently as of **Graph API 2.9**, properties such as `caption` or `description` are deprecated. Are there any replacements that will still allow me to apply some custom data to a description in the dialog?

Comment: Only Open Graph meta tags. So the only solution is to create an individual URL for that specific result you want to share.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

```
   FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': href,
                'og:title': quote,
                'og:image': img
            }
        })
    })
```